# DownloadManager handshake failure

Tags: android, tls1.2, android-download-manager, handshake

I'm trying to download some remote files using the Android DownloadManager and looks like there's some HTTPS certificate issues when running the app on Lollipop 5.0. Works fine on greater versions and I'm able to manually download the same files using OkHttp.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xaaf60a00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:765 0xa957ad35:0x00000000)
```

Is there anything I can do client-side? (e.g. force the DownloadManager using a specific protocol)
The remote host has just TLS 1.0 / 1.1 / 1.2 enabled, no SSL.

Also tried running some tests from my machine and I get the following:

```
> openssl s_client -connect <myhost>:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
24485:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.30.2/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:
```

Any hints will be highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do client-side? (e.g. force the DownloadManager using a specific protocol)

Only if you can provide some different URL that downloads the same thing but, for whatever reason, runs through a different server configuration that does not exhibit the problem. The classic example of this would be to use an `http` URL with `DownloadManager`. This would be unfortunate; OTOH, depending on your `minSdkVersion`, it might be necessary, as old Android versions (1.x/2.x IIRC) did not support `https` with `DownloadManager` in general.

Otherwise, `DownloadManager` is its own app, and you do not have fine-grained control over how it handles SSL.